# How do i simplify hundreds of resultset lines

Tags: java, loops, resultset

how do i simplify these lines. I have hundreds of these lines setting the value in each table cell.

```
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE Type = 'E-MAIL FAULT' AND No_Fault_Number <> 'No Fault Number' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 77, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE Type = 'E-MAIL FAULT' AND No_Fault_Number = 'No Fault Number' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 78, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE CMTS = 'SJ1' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 80, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE CMTS = 'SJ2' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 81, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE CMTS = 'SJ3' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 82, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE CMTS = 'ALA1' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 83, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE CMTS = 'ALA2' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 84, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE CMTS = 'FVW' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 85, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE CMTS = 'MND1' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 86, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE Call_Concern = 'Slow Connection' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 88, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE Call_Concern = 'No Connection' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 89, 1); 
         dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE Call_Concern = 'Intermittent Connection' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 90, 1);
```

Just looking at it makes me feel terrible and i need to find out is there a loop to simplify this? any type of help would be great.

Here is the method code btw.

```
  public void dailyResult(String q, int x, int y){

    try{
        Statement stmtDr = (Statement)daily.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmtDr.executeQuery(q);
    if(rs.next()){
        reportTable1.setValueAt(rs.getInt(1), x, y);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error 106\n\nAn error has occured with the resultset procedure method. Please try again later.", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Which database server are you using ? If MSSQL , you can use stored procedure & pass the variables you need to the procedure arguments. MySQL & Oracle DB have similar thing too

Comment: Parameterize the SQL statement, and hand it the correct day when executing it.  You'll only need one SQL statement.

Comment: @Shivan im using MySQL. how do i do that? sample code snippets please..

Comment: @Robert i really dont have any background about parameterizing sql statements, so i guess imma read more about this

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use group by in your queries, replace this

```
dailyResult("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE CMTS = 'MND1' AND CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year , 86, 1);
```

with

```
dailyResult("SELECT CMTS,COUNT(*) FROM fault WHERE CallTypeInt = 'TRI' AND DC_Month = " + month + " AND DC_Day = " + day + " AND DC_Year = " + year +" GROUP BY CMTS", 86, 1);
```

then in dailyResult

```
ResultSet rs = stmtDr.executeQuery(q);
while(rs.next()){  // we are expecting multiple rows now
    String faultType = rs.getString(1);//what fault is this?
    reportTable1.setValueAt(rs.getInt(2), getXOffset(faultType), y);
}
```

Something to be careful of is that if no faults are found then no row will be returned but that is the same behaviour as you have now, so I assume you are catering for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a stored procedure for these queries, and do use the *group by* command to reduce the length of the query.

Actually I noticed that CMTS, Call_Concern etc are being used for differently in each query. Perhaps you can bunch some of the queries into one, but I don't think all of them can be grouped together in the present format. Parameterize these columns. All of them. Perhaps you need to look into the business logic to do that. Once that is done, you can have just one query for the entire stuff.